# Juntar os Resultados de uma Array

Tags: php, array

Tenho uma aplicação em PHP que pega um arquivo Json e cria um array tazendo:

cidade |
bairro |
cidade |
complemento |
endereco |
estado

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$file = "data.json";
$info = file_get_contents($file);
$lendo = json_decode($info);
foreach($lendo->unidades as $campo){
    $result = array_unique($campo);
    print_r($result);
}
```

**data.json**

```
{
    "unidades": [{
    "bairro": "Ouro",
    "cidade": "São Mateus do Sul",
    "complemento": "&quot; &quot;",
    "endereco": "Rua XYZ ABADA, 26",
    "estado": "PR"
},
{
    "bairro": "Centro",
    "cidade": "Xinguara",
    "complemento": "&quot;TESTE TESTE TESTE&quot;",
    "endereco": "Rua ABC, 60",
    "estado": "PA"
},
{
    "bairro": "Prata",
    "cidade": "Wenceslau Braz",
    "complemento": "&quot; ZENFORM &quot;",
    "endereco": "Rua  HUEHUEHUE, 99",
    "estado": "PR"
  }]
}
```

Gostaria de saber se é possivel juntar os Resultados do Array por `estado` ou por `cidade` como o exemplo abaixo

```
Array
 (
  [bairro] => Ouro
  [cidade] => São Mateus do Sul
  [complemento] => &quot; &quot;
  [endereco] => Rua XYZ ABADA, 26
  [estado] => PR

  [bairro] => Prata
  [cidade] => Wenceslau Braz
  [complemento] => &quot; ZENFORM &quot;
  [endereco] => Rua  HUEHUEHUE, 99
  [estado] => PR

  [bairro] => Bronze
  [cidade] => Wenceslau Braz
  [complemento] => &quot; ALAMEDA &quot;
  [endereco] => Rua  CHAVEZ, 99
  [estado] => PR

 )

Array
 (
  [bairro] => Centro
  [cidade] => Xinguara
  [complemento] => &quot;TESTE TESTE TESTE&quot;
  [endereco] => Rua ABC, 60
  [estado] => PA


  [bairro] => Caçapa
  [cidade] => 2 irmãos
  [complemento] => &quot;TESTE TESTE TESTE&quot;
  [endereco] => Rua EFG, 88
  [estado] => PA

 )
```

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo do seu JSON? assim podemos testar melhor o código.

Comment: Editei a minha resposta com uma correção e exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Pode iterar essa array que vem do ficheiro e dentro desse loop popular/preencher uma nova array.

```
$ordenada = array();
foreach($lendo->unidades as $campo){
    $ordenada[$campo->estado][] = $campo;
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://ideone.com/DmSi0t

Desse modo vai ter uma nova array de arrays com este formato:

```
array(2) {
  ["PR"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (5) {
      ["bairro"]=>
      string(4) "Ouro"
      ["cidade"]=>
      string(18) "São Mateus do Sul"
      ["complemento"]=>
      string(13) "&quot; &quot;"
      ["endereco"]=>
      string(17) "Rua XYZ ABADA, 26"
      ["estado"]=>
      string(2) "PR"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (5) {
      ["bairro"]=>
      string(5) "Prata"
      ["cidade"]=>
      string(14) "Wenceslau Braz"
      ["complemento"]=>
      string(21) "&quot; ZENFORM &quot;"
      ["endereco"]=>
      string(18) "Rua  HUEHUEHUE, 99"
      ["estado"]=>
      string(2) "PR"
    }
  }
  ["PA"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (5) {
      ["bairro"]=>
      string(6) "Centro"
      ["cidade"]=>
      string(8) "Xinguara"
      ["complemento"]=>
      string(29) "&quot;TESTE TESTE TESTE&quot;"
      ["endereco"]=>
      string(11) "Rua ABC, 60"
      ["estado"]=>
      string(2) "PA"
    }
  }
}
```