# Juntar Arrays com php

Tags: php, sql, array, codeigniter

bom galera to fazendo um sistema e preciso retornar valores da sessão e do banco de dados mais queria isso dentro de uma única array, usando a função `array_unshift()` ele me retorna o seguinte

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [i_chamada] => 1
                            [i_interacao] => 19
                            [i_tecnico] => 
                            [i_cliente] => 1
                            [descricao] => texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto
                            [status] => N
                            [tecnico] => 
                            [dt_interacao] => 2015-04-02 09:09:25
                            [tempo] => 
                        )

                )

            [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1427979172
            [id_cli] => 1
            [email_cli] => saymon@rodriguesite.net
            [nome_cli] => LM Sistema
            [user_cli] => admin
            [pass_cli] => 123123
            [status_cli] => A
            [dtcad_cli] => 2015-03-31 09:26:38
            [logado_cli] => 1
            [tela] => pergunta
        )
```

e não consegui achar um forma de mesclar essas duas array, algo como elas ficassem assim:

```
            Array
        (
            [i_chamada] => 1
            [i_interacao] => 19
            [i_tecnico] => 
            [i_cliente] => 1
            [descricao] => texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto
            [status] => N
            [tecnico] => 
            [dt_interacao] => 2015-04-02 09:09:25
            [tempo] => 
            [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1427979172
            [id_cli] => 1
            [email_cli] => saymon@rodriguesite.net
            [nome_cli] => LM Sistema
            [user_cli] => admin
            [pass_cli] => 123123
            [status_cli] => A
            [dtcad_cli] => 2015-03-31 09:26:38
            [logado_cli] => 1
            [tela] => pergunta
        )
```

Comment: Alguma coisa me diz que já foi respondido antes. Alguém consegue achar? Talvez esta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42679/101

Comment: Acredito que essa pergunta vai te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611313/turning-multidimensional-array-into-one-dimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom galera consegui resolver da seguinte maneira, na hora que ele retorna a array com os valores do banco tenho algo como

```
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [i_chamada] => 1
                        [i_interacao] => 19
                        [i_tecnico] => 
                        [i_cliente] => 1
                        [descricao] => texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto
                        [status] => N
                        [tecnico] => 
                        [dt_interacao] => 2015-04-02 09:09:25
                        [tempo] => 
                    )
```

juntei as arrays com array_unshift($array, $array[0]), no segundo parâmetro utilizei o índice.